# Regex to hit parenthesis, but only in a specific way

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Entry in question:

> `BOREAS HYD-02 Estimated Snow Water Equivalent (SWE) from Microwave Measurements (BOREAS_H02SWED_256) - https://cmr.earthdata.nasa.gov:443/search/concepts/C179002851-ORNL_DAAC/30.umm-json`

I need a regex to hit

> `(BOREAS_H02SWED_256) - https://cmr.earthdata.nasa.gov:443/search/concepts/C179002851-ORNL_DAAC/30.umm-json`

from the entry below such that it yields

> `BOREAS HYD-02 Estimated Snow Water Equivalent (SWE) from Microwave Measurements`

My simple regex of `[(].*` is hitting

> `(SWE) from Microwave Measurements (BOREAS_H02SWED_256) - https://cmr.earthdata.nasa.gov:443/search/concepts/C179002851-ORNL_DAAC/30.umm-json`

Comment: Try: `\s\(BOREAS.*`

Comment: The issue is this section can change. So it won't always be 'BOREAS.' Maybe regex isn't the way to go?

Comment: What about [`\([^()]*\)\s*-\s*http.*`](https://regex101.com/r/lijXJ3/1)? What is static here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew trying this now with a few others, one sec...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay that's it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry about, I'm a noobie :) thank you for your help!

Comment: Please consider also upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\([^()]*\)\s*-\s*http.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lijXJ3/1).

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(`
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)`
- `\s*-\s*` - a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `http` - a literal `http` substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *space bracket non-blank underscore* marks the start of your target input to remove (ie replace with blank):

```
\s\(\S+_.*
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/rWkrn82D0P).

Or, to target the input to keep, use the above as a look ahead:

```
.*(?=\s\(\S+_)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/ns7fDicFS3).